# How to debug a Firefox search engine plugin?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firebug, search-engine

I am writing a search engine plugin for Firefox.

I want to implement [search suggestions](http://www.opensearch.org/Specifications/OpenSearch/Extensions/Suggestions/1.1), so I want my plugin to send requests to my server to get them.

In order to debug this functionality I need to see what requests have been sent and what response is returned.

I noticed that Firebug does not log this info. So I need something else. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

The add-on LiveHTTPHeaders works.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/

Also try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> and look at the *Network* tab, that will probably work, too, although I haven't used that before.

Comment: I can't see the response body, would you show me how(with screenshot)? I can only check if what it sends. I need the complete JSON which is returned.

Comment: Oh you can't see response body with LiveHTTPHeaders. But with a rest addon you can replicate that post and see the result there. https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/rest-easy/

Answer (score 0):

Tools-->Web Developer--->Browser Console(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>)

And in the tab of `Net`, check "Log Request and Response Bodies"